# Python Interface for Highcharts

Tags: python, html, highcharts

I was very happy when the Python Interface for Highcharts has been announced this week.
Now I am struggling to integrate it into a Web page.

Following this example https://core-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/#generate-the-javascript-code-for-your-chart
I tried to integrate the resulting Java Script file into my Web page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tescht</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<body>
  <script src="./my_target_file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, there’s not quite enough information here to fully diagnose what the issue might be. 

Can you share a snippet of the Python code you are using to produce “my_target_file.js”? Is it a direct copy from the tutorial, or something modified slightly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you open the html in the browser, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors in the browser console? Please see [ask].

Comment: If you're going to answer your question (which is OK here to do so), then please post the answer seperatley using the "Answer" button.

Comment: Thanks Jiminy! 
This was my first contribution.
I changed it according to your recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution!

The answer to my problem can be found here:

https://ahumbleopinion.com/highcharts-tips-accessing-chart-object-from-container-id/

The reference to a container ID was mssing.
My code now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <script src = "./my_target_file.js"></script>   
   </body>
</html>
```

In Java Script file the container is referenced like this:

```
// my_target_file.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
new Highcharts.chart("container",
{
...
},
);
});
```

Now the chart is rendered!